# I create office files in "MS word, Powerpoint, Access" can I see my Office files in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, word-documents

I create many office files in MS word. If I install Ubuntu can I see my MS word files?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure i understand your question,

If you are asking, if you can see documents made with Microsoft office in Ubuntu. the answer is yes.

Ubuntu has [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) already installed for you. and you can open .doc and .docx and ALL the Microsoft office files with it.(powerpoint, excel, etc...)

You can create documents in Ubuntu with LibreOffice in the same formats too.

If you have Ubuntu 11.10 installed, click the first icon on the launcher (on the left), and then type `libreoffice` and click the icon to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, MS office files such as .xls,.xlsx,.ppt,pptx,.doc,.docx are compatible with Libre Office. You can view and edit such files with Libre Office in Ubuntu.